# SQL Server 2017 Replication using FTP raise error Agent message code 20033. The process could not retrieve file from FTP server

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I'm try to use ftp in SQL Replication. My Publisher server is on Windows 10 Pro, with FTP enabled for the ftp folder in repldata. The subscriber is on Linux using container, both are SQL Server 2017 (I just want to try to replicate those server, it's not production server). On Windows I'm able to generate/create all the publisher and subscription via SMSS.

I use transactional replication.

The Publisher can and do generate the file in

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\repldata\ftp\BEN-ASUS-A43SV_COBA_COBAPUB`

and it's hoster on ftp folder /sql --> ftp folder in repldata

But the problem is, I always got error on when the sync jobs is running

The error is

```
2023-06-13 04:35:44.401 Initializing
2023-06-13 04:35:44.674 Snapshot files will be downloaded via ftp
2023-06-13 04:35:44.719 Connecting to ftp site '192.168.233.23'
2023-06-13 04:35:47.025 Agent message code 20033. The process could not retrieve file 'BEN-ASUS-A43SV_COBA_COBAPUB/20230613113602/nilai_2.pre' from the FTP site '192.168.233.23'.
2023-06-13 04:35:47.207 Category:OS
Source:  
Number:  12004
Message: An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions

2023-06-13 04:35:47.249 Category:COMMAND
Source:  Failed Command
Number:  
Message: if @@trancount > 0 rollback tran
2023-06-13 04:35:47.298 Category:AGENT
Source:  AGENT
Number:  
Message: The process could not retrieve file 'BEN-ASUS-A43SV_COBA_COBAPUB/20230613113602/nilai_2.pre' from the FTP site '192.168.233.23'.
```

I also see on the ftp log that the user is connecting, but seems just connect change directory, then disconnect, not asking any files... If I manually connect using same user, I can download the replication files.

```
06/13/2023 11:53:28 (not login 192.168.233.148<--192.168.233.23:21) "220 Xlight FTP Server 3.9 ready..."
06/13/2023 11:53:28 (not login 192.168.233.148-->192.168.233.23:21) "USER anonymous"
06/13/2023 11:53:28 (not login 192.168.233.148<--192.168.233.23:21) "331 Anonymous login OK, send your e-mail as password"
06/13/2023 11:53:29 (not login 192.168.233.148-->192.168.233.23:21) "PASS *****"
06/13/2023 11:53:29 (anonymous 192.168.233.148<--192.168.233.23:21) "230 Login OK"
06/13/2023 11:53:29 (anonymous 192.168.233.148-->192.168.233.23:21) "CWD /sql"
06/13/2023 11:53:29 (anonymous 192.168.233.148<--192.168.233.23:21) "250 Directory successfully changed"
06/13/2023 11:53:29 (anonymous 192.168.233.148-->192.168.233.23:21) "TYPE I"
06/13/2023 11:53:29 (anonymous 192.168.233.148<--192.168.233.23:21) "200 Type set to I."
```

Is there anyway to debug this further why The subscriber can't download the transactional file?

Thank you